# Excel PivotTable: How do you calculate the difference between a two columns in a multileveled PivotTable?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

So say I have a pretty simple PivotTable, with reach record having Month, Type, Lodging and Lodg. Tax.

My records are uniquely organized by Date and by Type (with Types being "Estimate" and "Real").

I want to be able to do things like calculate the difference between our estimates and our real costs.  Is there a way to do that with PivotTables?

Ideally, it'd do something like determine a total difference instead of a total sum, as seen below (on the right).

[image]

Comment: In your data, add a helper column labeled something like "Diff", containing `=income-expenses` (where income and expenses are references to those cells).  Include that column in the values window of the pivot table aggregated with Sum.  You'll get the differences for whatever rows/groups are the pivot table rows and a grand total if you want it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't quite cover what I'm looking for.  Say I have Day 1, Region A, listed as 1A.  I don't want 1A Income - 1A Expense, but I instead want 1A Income - 1B Income, and 1A Expense - 1B Expense.

Comment: This would be easier for people to help with if you provide a screenshot or mock-up of the spreadsheet, and an example based on that, which illustrates what you need to do.  I'm only guessing that A and B are on the same row.  If so, the same approach would do it.  Use one helper column for A income - B income, and another for A expenses - B expenses.  Then include both helper columns.

Comment: @fixer1234 Seems like my worries are confirmed.  From the sound of it, there's no real way of using PivotTable to come up with a way to generate differences for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe and maybe not.  No way to tell without the detail.  It could just be a matter of setting up some calculations in helper columns to feed the pivot table.

Comment: @fixer1234 Good point.  Uploaded a picture, and reworded the question to better show an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: What should happen in cases like the first record, where there is no "real" value (or no estimate)?  How are you getting the sums in the last columns?

Comment: @fixer1234 Those entries should be removed from the PivotTable.  I can have a filter that removes records with blank entries for certain fields, but it seems to ignore that filter when it's a multileveled pivottable (if I remove the "Type" superlevel, it obeys the filter, otherwise it populates all records).  Unfortunately, that means it sums both the Real and Estimate entries for all fields, which isn't useful.  Kinda frustrating, seems like PivotTable isn't designed well for multileveled functions.  I suppose a functional way to do it is replace one of the tables with negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view a difference. What about this workaround:

1. Create a new count field: Click on Analyze card -> Fields, Items & Sets -> Count field
2. Name it e.g. Lodgingdiff and the formula would be

```
= Lodging
```

3. Then add the Lodgingdiff into the Values in the Pivot table
4. Go to Field settings -> Show Values As -> Choose Difference from, set Base field as "Type" and Base Item as e.g. "Estimate"

It add a new column into the Pivot Table with difference of real Lodging from estimated Lodging. You can see the difference bellow the column Real | Sum of Lodgingdiff.
Best regards, Lukáš